# Javascript typeof of undefined objects subproperty

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let's say I would like to check if a property to the object Foo is defined or not, I would use in this scenario:

```
typeof Foo.property != 'undefined'
```

But if not only the property does not exists, but also the object is undefined, this results in an error.

Is there any single line way to check if an objects property is defined, and return false in the following cases:

- if the object property is not defined
- if the object is not defined

**WHY I WANT THIS:** I am writing a script in NodeJS, which uses a class, which would be used in the front end also, and instead of maintaining two different files, which would end up being basically the same except for minor changes for the two environments, I would like to differentiate between the environments with some basic IF logic.

**OTHER POSSIBLE USE CASES:** Let's say we have the following object:

```
function Foo() {
  this.case1={
       info1: 'something',
       info2: 'something',
       .....
       info1000: 'something'
  }

  this.case2={
       info1: 'something',
       info2: 'something',
       ......
       info1000: 'something'
  }
}
```

If I would like to decide which case applies to me, and the decision lies in one of the inner info's, I would first have to check if the respective case exists, and then if the respective info exists(2 conditions):

```
  if (typeof Foo.case1 != 'undefined') && (typeof Foo.case1.info1 != 'undefined')
```

If this is a much deeper nested object, there would be a lot of condition checking and typing, to get some basic information: if case1 does not exist at all, then I will use case2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I came up with a small function, which on initial testing does what I wanted, but I've only tested it for like 5 minutes, so there could be errors in it, if yes, please point it out:

```
function isDefined(path, namespace) {
    if (typeof namespace == 'undefined') {
        namespace=global; 
        // global is the default namespace for NodeJS, 
        // change this to window if you use it in a browser
    }
    path=path.split(".");
    for (var i=0;i<path.length ;i++)
    {

        if (typeof namespace[path[i]] == 'undefined') return false;
        else namespace=namespace[path[i]];
    }

    return true;
}
```

Usage: if you would want to test for example if Test.Test1.Test2.Test3.Test4.Test5.Test6 is defined you can use it like this:

```
if (isDefined('Test.Test1.Test2.Test3.Test4.Test5.Test6')===true) { 
  //it is defined
}
```

Comment: A small tip for portability; an environment-neutral way to find the `global` object is to run an IIFE with no call arguments, and `this` will be the global on the inside of it.

Comment: Unfortunatly I don't know what an IIFE is, but if you care to either EDIT my answer, or add a new answer using that method, I would upvote/accept it:)

Comment: Immediately Invoked Function Expression. So, like this: `var global; (function() { global = this; })();`

Answer (score 4):

You could use an **and** (`&&`) clause.

```
typeof Foo !== 'undefined' && typeof Foo.property !== 'undefined'
```

Or put more simply:

```
Foo !== undefined && Foo.property !== undefined
```

**Edit:** As [David Titarenco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243613/david-titarenco) pointed out, this works due to something known as short-circuit evaluation. That basically means that if the first part evaluates to false (`Foo !== undefined`) then the second part is never evaluated.

Comment: Just wanted to point out (for OP's sake) that the order of operands is important here. This is called *short-circuit evaluation*.

Comment: Totally agree with Mike C's i read about it in a awesome book called JavaScript the good parts by Douglas crockford.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that I can do this this way, but take a look at OTHER USE CASES in my question please. With a deeply nested object, I would have to type each property separatly, until I arrive at the single property which I am interested in, instead of checking for that single property.

Comment: @AdamBaranyai Unless you have the chain of properties in something like an array (`['case1', 'info1']`) then that's just something you have to deal with.

Comment: Note that `Foo !== undefined` will throw an error if `Foo` is *undeclared*.  Otherwise, it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer that comes to mind is this. It is not as 100%-strict as yours, but it would take a very unusual situation to break it:

```
if (Foo && 'property' in Foo) {
```

The `Foo` object is evaluated as boolean. A null or undefined type will be false, any object will be true. We also check the "key" side of the key/value pair, rather than the value. It is technically possible to *have* the key `property`, but for it to have the actual value `undefined`. This will return false in that case.

The one caveat: If `Foo` is another value type: `true`, `12`, `function()...`, then the first condition may pass (but I don't believe the second one will)